# Strange characters like: � are appearing when using mcrypt_decrypt on CentOS

Tags: php, mysql, database, encryption, character-encoding

I want to encrypt access tokens, and decrypt it at some point.

The content of my table looks like this: 
[image]

I used the built-in function of Mysql AES_ENCRYPT() in the following way:

```
UPDATE users SET access_token = AES_ENCRYPT('adummyaccesstoken', '1234567890123456') WHERE id = 1;
```

On WAMP my code looks like this:

```
try{
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "";
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}

$statement = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id = 1");
$statement->execute();
$row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

$row['decrypted_token'] = trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '1234567890123456', $row['access_token'], MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
var_dump($row);
```

On WAMP the result is this:

```
array (size=5)
  'id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'firstname' => string 'Pim' (length=3)
  'lastname' => string 'van der Wal' (length=11)
  'access_token' => string 'Äk„
vl¢Þ?ÍØ%tkÑ²úiLï4]«~Ô‡íW' (length=32)
  'decrypted_token' => string 'adummyaccesstoken' (length=32)
```

I applied the same approach to my webapplication which is running on CentOS.

```
$decryptToken = trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '1234567890123456', $this->accessToken, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
echo $decryptToken;
```

Result:

```
��m�N��kA��%+��q���/��Ĝx��ϐۊ�e  �/+�d�@vU��
```

**Question**
I can't understand why it returns the code in such a weird way. I suspect that this has to do with a character set mismatch when reading the decrypted token.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you have to use htmlentity_encode / decode. Store encoded data in database and show it on browser before decode

Comment: I tried `rtrim()`, and the issue remained the same.

Comment: Similar problem: http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/123592-mcrypt-decrypt-not-returning-original-string-returning-weird-data-no-errors/

Comment: Nowhere in your code you set the database connection encoding

Comment: Save yourself some trouble: Instead of using `AES_ENCRYPT()` and [mcrypt, which you should not be using](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong), choose a [sane PHP cryptography library](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/11/choosing-right-cryptography-library-for-your-php-project-guide).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The encrypted data is binary - it doesn't have character representation or encoding - **it's not text**

The result show here:

```
'access_token' => string 'Äk„
vl¢Þ?ÍØ%tkÑ²úiLï4]«~Ô‡íW' (length=32)
```

is probably the iso-8895-1 interpretation of the binary. Note how something in the binary data has matched carriage return - that'll be `0A`. `²` = `B2`, and so on.
You'll see this if you use the Windows console or open the file in notepad.

The result you're seeing on CentOS is probably because your terminal or editor is configured for UTF-8. Any bytes sent to the terminal are interpreted as UTF-8. In UTF-8, most bytes above 7F will need matching surrogate bytes, which a near random string won't have produced, hence the replaced characters.

As you're storing binary data in the database, ensure that your field for the token is a blob and not varchar. Using varchar will lead to text character-translation problems.

In short, you don't need to worry as the underlying data is the same.

Comment: Super! I changed the column type to blob in phpmyadmin and it worked!

Comment: Altough I have to mention one thing. After altering the table, to let it work, the `UPDATE` query had to be executed once again.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of altering the table by setting a `blob` type to the access token column you could still use `VARCHAR` but in-combination with `base64_encode()` / `base64_decode()`.

Please look at this code:

```
//Scenario: encrypting
//The value of $encryptedToken needs to be stored in the db
$encryptedToken  = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, 'akey', 'anaccesstoken', MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));

//Scenario: decryption
$decryptedToken = trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, base64_decode($accessToken), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
```